# Javascript - Adding values dynamically in object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in the Javascript

```
var data = {
                    itemFromIndex :  status.next,
                    requestId :      status.requestId,
                    loggedInAdminId: self.loggedInAdminId,
                    fetchedAllTerms : status.fetchedAllTerms
       }
```

How can i add an another item later into the  data object?
like i want to add

```
dbTermsFetchToIndex : status.dbTermsFetchToIndex
```

into data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, that's not an array, it's an object literal. Second, yes you can:

```
data.dbTermsFetchToIndex = status.dbTermsFetchToIndex;
```

Will have the same effect as if you declared it in your object literal in the first place.

Comment: also i tried    data['dbTermsFetchToIndex'] = status.dbTermsFetchToIndex; Is this an other alternate, correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @SangramAnand Yes - that is an alternative.